# Cygwin can't find the "top" command

Tags: cygwin, command-line-interface

When I want to run `top` I get a message saying that the command cannot be found. I had a similar problem with the nano text editor. I resolved that by installing the nano package from the Cygwin installer a second time. Is there a particular package I need to install for `top` as well?

Comment: Not a programming question - try [su] ?

Answer (score 2):

matzeri's answer points to the search page http://cygwin.com/packages/.

Unfortunately, searching for `top` gives 2475 matches, and `\<top\>`gives 159 matches.  Searching for `/usr/bin/top` gives 3 matches (two versions of `procps-debuginfo` and one of `procps-ng-debuginfo`), but none of them is *quite* the correct package.

I ran `dpkg -S /usr/bin/top` on my Linux system to see which package provides the `top` command.  The result is `procps`, which is the same name as the corresponding Cygwin package.

(The question is off-topic for Stack Overflow. I think the answers will be migrated to Super User along with the question if there are enough close votes.)

Answer (score 1):

Use the cygwin search to find which package has top
http://cygwin.com/packages/